# Representing solutions of the system of linear equatons as linear manifold

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a system of 4 linear equations:
$$ 5x - 3y + 2z + 4t = 3,$$
$$ 4x - 2y + 3z + 7t = 1,$$
$$ 3x - 6y - z - 5t = 9,$$
$$ 7x - 3y + 7z + 47t = a,$$
where $ a \in \Bbb{R}$, and i have to represent the solutions of this system as linear manifold ($L = a + W$, where $a$ is vector, W is subspace of vector space. I think this is called linear manifold in English, but corect me if i'm wrong). I found that the solutions of the system are next:
$$ (x, y, z, t) = \left( 0, \frac{-a - 1050}{750}, \frac{-65a - 450}{750}, \frac{a}{30} \right).$$

This ordered 4-tuple can be written as $\left( 0, \frac{-21}{15}, \frac{-9}{15}, 0\right) + a\left( 0, \frac{-1}{750}, \frac{-65}{750}, \frac{1}{30}\right)$, $a \in \Bbb{R}$.

I just want to ask if next formula is the linear manifold i need:
$$L = \left( 0, \frac{-21}{15}, \frac{-9}{15}, 0\right) + \mathcal{L} \left\{\left( 0, \frac{-1}{750}, \frac{-65}{750}, \frac{1}{30}\right)\right\} ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the symbol $\mathcal{L} \left\{\left( 0, \frac{-1}{750}, \frac{-65}{750}, \frac{1}{30}\right)\right\}$ means the linear space spanned by the vector $\left( 0, \frac{-1}{750}, \frac{-65}{750}, \frac{1}{30}\right)$ than , Yes, you are correct. But I cannot verify your calculations and [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5x-3y%2B2z%2B4t%3D3,4x-2y%2B3z%2B7t%3D1,%203x-6y-z-5t%3D9,7x-3y%2B7z%2B47t%3Da) gives a different solution: for the system

$$
(x,y,z,t)=\left(0\;,-\frac{7}{5}-\frac{a}{75}\;,-\frac{3}{5}-\frac{13a}{150}\;,\frac{a}{30}\right)
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I just wanted to confirm is my process correct. $\mathcal{L}$ stands for lineal (linear combinations of the given vectors).

Comment: You are welcome !  This linear combination is called  **the linear span** ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span